# Difference between confint and predict

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression, confidence-interval

I'm analyzing a linear model with 2 factors and I need to find a confidence interval for the response variable. As I understand it `confint()` and `predict(, interval='confidence')` both find confidence intervals so what is the difference between them?

Comment: R object documentation can be displayed by either `help("name")` or `?name`. `?confint` and `?predict` will display the documentation information found in the answer @BenBolker provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `confint()` finds confidence intervals on the *model parameters*
- `predict(., interval="confidence")` finds confidence intervals on the *model predictions*

Comment: Ok thank you makes sense. If i have a model defined like 
`lm(effect ~ blok+treatment-1)` 
it seems like i cant add the confint intervals together to get the predict confidence interval? I dont really get this it seems counter intuitive that the parameter intervals isn't additive if the model is?

Comment: You can't do that for at least two reasons: (1) uncertainty is additive on the variance scale, not the standard deviation scale; (2) you have to take the correlation among the parameters into account when combining uncertainty.  See e.g.  [this CrossValidated question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/186844/error-propagation-in-a-linear-model)